# Make the WebView Display in a Box like the WebControl Tool

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, awesomium

In the Awesomium 1.7 examples is shown how to use an entire window to render the `WebView` output.
I want it to be within a box in my form (not the whole form like in the example so I can have buttons) like their `WebControl` Tool.
I cannot use their WebControl Tool directly because I need to emulate keyboard input and the WebControl doesn't allow that.
So what is the simplest way of doing this as I have no idea currently.
I'm asking here because I got no response on the Awesomium forums for several weeks now

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can render the `WebView` in a custom WinForms `Control`, rather than a `Form`. Then add this control to your form and place it accordingly.
2. The user-input API is still available in the `WebControl`. The members are just *protected*. You can subclass the `WebControl` and call these methods yourself.